# DSC Environment resource failing to see environment variable it has set

Tags: dsc, powershell-v5.0

I'm using DSC to provision virtual machines.  The VMs are setup to pull a DSC configuration from a pull server.  All is well with this.  However, I noticed that I am frequently seeing:

```
Job {8B376B76-EDE7-11E6-80FC-3649808F2EC1} : 
From LCM, message is 
    Completed processing test operation. The operation returned False.
```

In the event logs.  Using a useful tip I found here https://powershell.org/forums/topic/lcm-event-log-entries-for-different-configurationmode-settings/, I can see that an Environment variable resource is failing - despite the fact that the environment variable was created:

```
VERBOSE: [TESTEZE-CDEUURA]: LCM:  [ Start  Resource ]  [[Environment]EZELOGS]
VERBOSE: [TESTEZE-CDEUURA]: LCM:  [ Start  Test     ]  [[Environment]EZELOGS]
VERBOSE: [TESTEZE-CDEUURA]:                            [[Environment]EZELOGS] (NOT FOUND) Environment variable 'EZELOGS'
VERBOSE: [TESTEZE-CDEUURA]: LCM:  [ End    Test     ]  [[Environment]EZELOGS] False in 0.0190 seconds.
VERBOSE: [TESTEZE-CDEUURA]: LCM:  [ End    Resource ]  [[Environment]EZELOGS]
```

(I know the environment variable was created because I can see it in the environment variables dialog).

If I manually reboot the machine, the consistency check then passes.

My LCM configuration is set to `RebootIfNeeded=$true` and `ActionAfterReboot = 'ContinueConfiguration'`.

The resource definition is this:

```
Environment EZELOGS {
    Name = "EZELOGS"
    Value = "C:\Logs"
    Ensure = "Present"
}
```

The LCM is *creating* the variable, but it does not seem to be able to *see* the variable, and ends up cycling the configuration every 30mins.  Any pointers?

Environment is Windows Server 2012 R2 (I know, I know...), with Powershell 5, WMF 5.0 (from KB3134758)

Comment: I haven't looked at the code, but odds are it's setting the environment variable in a way that requires a process restart for the LCM to see it.  You're using a built-in resource?

Comment: Sure, and a reboot clears it.  I am using the OOTB "Environment" resource and it would appear to be buggy in that it neither updates the processes runtime environment, nor does it request a reboot to pick up the change...